# Objective C - Initializer element is not constant

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

Really beginner question here.

I have an NSArray of images which in its last line has an error in Xcode saying that the "initializer element is not constant".

any help please?

Comment: Show us the code for a real answer, but in this case, it sounds like you have a bad global variable declaration/initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initializing your NSArray outside of a valid scope (ie, not inside a function or method).

For example, the following will produce your error:

```
NSArray * foo = [NSArray array];
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  return 0;
}
```

To fix it, you'd do something like:

```
NSArray * foo = nil;
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  foo = [NSArray array];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked, I am still a little used to java, trying to learn objective c and the iphone framework in parallel.

I have a problem with the code, I am trying to load an image to set the background image depending on whether the user chooses next or previous button. 

I am calling the object at an index which I increment or decrement and I can see that the counter is increasing and decreasing accordingly when they press the buttons. 

What would the could look like to set the background of my view controller?